# How to update data of parent component after database update?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-functional-component

I have roughly the following component structure:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    //update data from api
}, [])
return <Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${match.path}`}>
        {data.map(row=>
            <Link to={`${match.url}/${row.id}`}></List>
        }
    </Route>
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`}>
        <Form>
        </Form>
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

When I update data in `<Form>` component, how do I force react to update `data` from api? In this case, rerun the `useEffect` I used to update the api.

**EDIT**

The way I solved the problem is like this:

```
const [toggle,toggler] = useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
    //update from api
},[toggle]);

return <Form toggleFunction={toggler}>
```

I am wondering if there is a *proper* solution

Comment: Ciao, your solution is the correct one. At least, of you want to avoid to pass prop on Form component, you could use react-redux. But your solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, try this code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);
useEffect(()=>{
    //update data from api
}, [update])

const makeUpdate = () => {
   let curr_val = update;
   setUpdate(!curr_val);
};

return <Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${match.path}`}>
        {data.map(row=>
            <Link to={`${match.url}/${row.id}`}></List>
        }
    </Route>
    <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`}>
        <Form onUpdate={makeUpdate}>
        </Form>
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

Then, on `Form` component, when you have to update, just call `props.onUpdate()`.

Explanation: pass function as prop in `Form` component. Then, on `makeUpdate` I change parent state value and connect `useEffect` to this one (on deps list).

Answer (score 1):

well i think you should send a prop to Form component a method that will use the function

```
const onSubmit = (e)=> {
}
<Form onSubmit={(e)=> a method}/>
```

another solution is to use Effect like this:

```
    useEffect(()=> {
     //called data
     setState(false);
    },[statepick]);
   <Form isSubmit={(e)=>setState(true)}
```

I prefer to use the function one because you just call the API when needed and useEffect will change the stuff if need after you update the data State.
In addition, change the useEffect to this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    //update data from api
},[])
```

because without brackets it will be called after everything!!! and in this scenario you will be called only when the component render for the first time

Answer (score 1):

You can use official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) as inspiration and try to write your component like this:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  // send data on submit
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Sending name [${name}] to API...`);
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildForm value={name} handleChange={handleChange} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
  );
}

const ChildForm = props => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={props.value} onChange={props.handleChange} />
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In this example you send request to the API on "Submit" click.